# Executing mocha test for monaco-editor integration

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, monaco-editor

I can not get my tests for my monaco-editor integration to run because I always get the following error: `Error: Cannot find module 'monaco-editor'`

I'm running the following: `mocha -r ts-loader -r esm "./src/test/typescript/*.test.ts"`

To reproduce this, just use the following:

```
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';
console.log(monaco.languages);
```

I read that the monaco-editor package does not follow the node module convention and needs a custom loader, but compiling with `tsc` seems to work just fine. I also tried getting a mocha-webpack test to run with the monaco editor webpack plugin but that also failed.

Can anyone help me get this running or point me to an example? I'm using the latest versions. Here my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "monaco-editor": "^0.20.0",
    "monaco-editor-webpack-plugin": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "mocha": "^7.2.0",
    "mochapack": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.11",
    "@types/mocha": "^7.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.5",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "mocha -r ts-loader -r esm \"./src/test/typescript/*.test.ts\""
  }
```